# Can I copy & paste a SQL result that is over 1 million rows long into Excel?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I have been running a mammoth SQL query that is as so:

```
select SessionID, PID, RespondentID
from BIG_Sessions (nolock)
where RespondentID in (

'1407718',
'1498288',
/* ETC ETC */


)
```

I heard that Excel has a maximum of  1 million rows.  Not sure how to approach this

Table BIG_Sessions is huge. It is pulling multiple SessionID's for a given RespondentID - but I only want one each.

I don't know how to winnow this. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: So is your query pulling the records you want?

Comment: For the curious, Excel <2007 has a maximum of 65.536 rows. Excel >=2007 has a maximum of  1.048.576 rows.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is it about whether Excel supports that many rows (which is off-topic here)? Or is it about how to improve your query (which is)?

Comment: Why would you want to..? If you're already programming, why not do whatever analysis you need within PHP (or another language that makes sense for your project)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data - 1 million rows is rather large to browse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version of Excel you are using.  [2010 apparently supports "over one million".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514.aspx) While [2003 only supports a little over 65,000](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx).

Personally I would export it to a CSV file.  Just right click on your result set and select "Save Results As...".  No limit there.

Answer (score 1):

An answer purely related to Excel: 
I have tried to put data in excess of 50,000 rows into Excel before. When I try, one of two things happen.

1) It actually works, but Excel is extremely slow, unresponsive, and often crashes. The data is basically unusable.
2) I fill up my RAM and Excel crashes, sometimes taking other programs with it.

If you are trying to copy 1,000,000 rows.... I would seriously doubt Excel could handle it!
Databases were created for handling exactly this situation: organizing large amounts of data. See if you can't do what you are trying to accomplish with Excel from within your database.